# Asp.net Identity password hashing

Tags: asp.net, security, identity, asp.net-identity

The new ASP.net Identity project has brought some useful code and interfaces for website security. To implement a custom system using the interfaces (instead of using the standard Entity Framework implementation included in the MVC 5 template) an `IPasswordHasher` is required.

#### `IPasswordHasher` interface in ASP.net Identity

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
{
    public interface IPasswordHasher
    {
         string HashPassword(string password);
         PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string providedPassword);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use password salting for more secure encryption in ASP.net Identity and via this interface?

Comment: Just salt the password before you pass it in.

Comment: Would the `string providedPassword` also need to be hashed?

Comment: Although they do offer ways to use your own hasher, it is strongly **not** recommended. Also, the default hasher already salts the password, otherwise hashing the same password twice would provide similar results.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> "Is it possible to use password salting for more secure encryption in
>   ASP.net Identity and via this interface?"

Yes, the interface is provided for the new implementation of PasswordHasher already present in Core framework.

Also note that the default implementation is already using Salt+Bytes.

After creating custom `PasswordHasher` (say `MyPasswordHasher`), you can assign it to UserManager instance like `userManager.PasswordHasher=new MyPasswordHasher()`

[See one example of such IPasswordHasher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530431/how-to-set-password-rules-for-asp-net-identity/19533614#19533614)

> To implement a custom system using the interfaces (instead of using the standard Entity Framework implementation included in the MVC 5 template) an IPasswordHasher is required.

For implementing alternate system from EF,
- You shall implement all Core interfaces.
- IPasswordHasher implementation is not required. PasswordHasher is already provided in Core framework as it's implementation.

Answer (score 60):

**HEALTH WARNING** for the below answer: Know which version of ASP.Net Identity you are using. You should refer to the source code directly if it is one of the newer versions from the github repository.

As I write this, the current version ([3.0.0-rc1/.../PasswordHasher.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/3.0.0-rc1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/PasswordHasher.cs)) of the password handler is significantly different to the below answer. This newer version supports multiple hash algorithm versions and is documented as (and may change further by the time you read this):

> Version 2:
>
> - PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA1, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 1000 iterations.
> - (See also: SDL crypto guidelines v5.1, Part III)
> - Format: `{ 0x00, salt, subkey }`
>
> Version 3:
>
> - PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA256, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 10000 iterations.
> - Format: `{ 0x01, prf (UInt32), iter count (UInt32), salt length (UInt32), salt, subkey }`
> - (All UInt32s are stored big-endian.)

The original answer is still valid *for the original version of ASP.Net Identity*, and is as follows:

---

@jd4u is correct, but to shed a little more light which wouldn't fit into a comment for his answer:

- `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher : IPasswordHasher` already salts for you,

  - more importantly it uses `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` to generate the salt and the hash,
  - which uses industry standard PBKDF2 ([SE discussion here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846), OWASP [recommendation for PBKDF2 here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function)).
- The default [`Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<TUser>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468199%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) implementation uses [`Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.passwordhasher%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) as a concrete `IPasswordHasher`
- `PasswordHasher` in turn is a really simple wrapper for (ultimately)[`System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So, if you are going to use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, just use `PasswordHasher` - all the heavy lifting is already done (hopefully correctly) for you.

**Details**

The full code that PasswordHasher (currently) ultimately uses does something very close to:

```cs
int saltSize = 16;
int bytesRequired = 32;
byte[] array = new byte[1 + saltSize + bytesRequired];
int iterations = SOME; // 1000, afaik, which is the min recommended for Rfc2898DeriveBytes
using (var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltSize, iterations))
{
    byte[] salt = pbkdf2.Salt;        
    Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, array, 1, saltSize);
    byte[] bytes = pbkdf2.GetBytes(bytesRequired);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, array, saltSize+1, bytesRequired);
}
return Convert.ToBase64String(array);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I needed a new method separate from user manager to create my hashed passwords and this worked perfectly

Comment: This is the most useful explanation I found so far, a default hasher is embed on the framework so when I save a user I just do this

var hash = new PasswordHasher().HashPassword(userViewModel.Password);
var userAggregate = UserAggregate.Create(userViewModel.Username, userViewModel.Email, hash, DateTime.Now.ToString());

Comment: http://vimeo.com/97530814  Minute 58, Troy Hunt also says 1,000  hash iterations.

Comment: 1) It's a bad idea to use a 32 byte output with PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1. Outputting more than the native size (20 bytes) slows down the defender by a factor 2 without slowing down the attacker at all. 2) 1000 iterations if a bit on the low side.

Comment: Here's how it looks like right now https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/37d4e2b6ff3e64985f0fa7017108b164dce9233b/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/PasswordHasher.cs

It changed from what's described above
https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/commit/37d4e2b6ff3e64985f0fa7017108b164dce9233b

Comment: Is Asp.net Identity using PBKDF2 to hash password?

Comment: So, if I'm reading this answer (and source) correctly, the default password hasher for AspNet.Identity 2.0 uses PBKDF2-HMACSHA1 with 1,000 iterations.  This is out of the box and I have to do nothing.  Once I upgrade to Core, it will use version 3 which does HMACSHA256 at 10,000 iterations.  It looks like you'll also be able to select which version you want, 2 or 3, and you'll be able to set the iterations via the PasswordHasher options constructor.  Can someone just confirm this for me?

Answer (score 9):

I ran into an issue while updating from Membership to AspNet.Identity. The Rfc2898 hashes are different from those used before. That's for good reason, but changing the hashes would require all users to reset their passwords. As a solution this custom implementation makes it backwards compatible:

```
public class MyPasswordHasher : PasswordHasher {

   public FormsAuthPasswordFormat FormsAuthPasswordFormat { get; set; }

   public MyPasswordHasher(FormsAuthPasswordFormat format) {
      FormsAuthPasswordFormat = format;
   }

   public override string HashPassword(string password) {
      return FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password, FormsAuthPasswordFormat.ToString());
   }

   public override PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string providedPassword) {
     var testHash = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(providedPassword, FormsAuthPasswordFormat.ToString());
     return hashedPassword.Equals(testHash) ? PasswordVerificationResult.Success : PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
   }
}
```

Once you create your UserManager instance just set the hasher:

```
Usermanager.PasswordHasher = new MyPasswordHasher(FormsAuthPasswordFormat.SHA1);
```

The code complains that the `HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile` method is deprecated, but that's fine as we know that the whole exercise is to get rid of the old technology.

Comment: This is great.  I have the same issue in that I want to migrate thousands of users from the Membership provider to the new ASP.Identity.  I will give it a try.

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing also. I wanted to point out that your constructor name is incorrect (should be `MyPasswordHasher(...)`. For my implementation, I also update the user's password when logging in to use the new hashing functionality using some of the examples here: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: I have fixed the copy and paste mistake.

Comment: I am trying to do the same but not succeed.. VerifyHashedPassword method first argument refer to the db table AspNetUsers column PasswordHash, right? What I would suppose to put in this column from the old membership column? Only password or password along with salt?