# Is it possible to use asp.net identity with an existing collection of usernames and passwords?

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I currently have a site that is using a handrolled authentication system of usernames and passwords - I do not have the ability to change the current database tables which store the usernames and passwords (the system has been in place for a long time).

Is it possible to use the new asp.net Identity system with existing data?  Mapping the columns somehow?  I have not seen anything like that in the documentation.

Comment: If you're using SQL Membership database, there's a tutorial on this: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity. Otherwise you may be required to implement your own provider, which might be overkill.

Comment: It is not asp.net membership, sadly - it is not a bad handmade memberhsip system, but it is eight years old and the author is no longer with the company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping to the table is the easy part.  Its the password encryption/decryption that will be difficult.

You might have to do a permissions migration over to claims or roles.

You simply create a user class with all the fields that match your current db table, and you'll have to add the new ones required by identity 2.0.

```
var mgr = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>());

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
      public string allMyNewFields {get; set;}
}
```

you will have to implement IPasswordHasher to get the passwords stuff.

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher : IPasswordHasher
```

checkout 
[Asp.net Identity password hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957176/asp-net-identity-password-hashing)

good luck