# .net Identity password encryption level

Tags: .net, hash, passwords, cryptography, identity

Does anyone know what type of encryption (salt+string) used by .net Indentity.  Our security folks want us to use at least SHA256.  I know I can override their encrption.  But would rather stick with what comes out of the box if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It uses SHA1 for HMACSHA1, as it uses the standard [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) class if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21496255/589259) is indeed correct.

Note that the use of SHA-1 for PBKDF2 is not really an issue with regard to cryptographic security. Note that SHA-1 or SHA-2 are both hash functions, not encryption.

Comment: very good!  Thanks for the quick feedback and the note of irony!

Comment: and actually they are worth their salt... it's just poor me who should have known the difference.

Comment: There is something to be said to be using SHA-2 as hash function for everything. It makes it easier to validate the security for the entire project. But SHA-1 is the default for PBKDF2 and is likely not going to be a problem - at least not for retrieving relatively short key material.

Comment: If this answered your question, then don't forget to accept it. Or indicate why it doesn't otherwise, of course.