# ASPNET Identity 2.0 hashing algorithm

Tags: asp.net-identity

Which Hashing Algorithm aspnet identity 2.0 uses to hash password. Is it SHA1 or SHA256 ? Is it possible to change to SHA2 if it uses SHA1 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Identity default Password Hasher, how does it work and is it secure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621950/asp-net-identity-default-password-hasher-how-does-it-work-and-is-it-secure)

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957176/asp-net-identity-password-hashing

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft is using PBKDF2 as their hashing algorithm in Identity 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net Identity 2.0 uses SHA1. It relies on [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx) and does not have any SHA256 option--you'd have to write your own implementation.

Asp.net Identity 3.0 does have an SHA256 option though.

Comment: Thanks mat , need to check identity 3.0