# ASP.Net Identity change Password Hashing method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm developing an MVC 5 web application with an existing database. 
I'm also using ASP.Net Identity for my Authorisation and Authentication but in database passwords are not Hashed using Identitys default password hasher, i need to change it with my own hasher. any idea?

Comment: Read: [Encrypt and Decrypt](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-Username-or-Password-stored-in-database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) This will help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After creating UserManager instance, you need to assign the passwordhasher property to your CustomPasswordHasher.

```
UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
UserManager.PasswordHasher = new CustomPasswordHasher();
```

"CustomPasswordHasher" Class should implement "IPasswordHasher" interface

you can see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530431/how-to-set-password-rules-for-asp-net-identity/19533614#19533614)