# sql query to md5 hash equivalent of c# code

Tags: c#, sql-server

referring to these articles:

(1) [Use md5 to encrypt the password in asp.net .core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57310305/use-md5-to-encrypt-the-password-in-asp-net-core/71779125#71779125)

(2) [Generate MD5 hash string with T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525997/generate-md5-hash-string-with-t-sql)

they don't produce the same result. Does anyone know what sql will produce the same as in code? (1) ?

Comment: If the information in the links is important, include it in the question using the correct citation rules. Links should support your question, but not be mandated to be visited to be able to answer your question. This is true even if the content is here on [so].

Comment: md5 is obsolete for security sensitive usages since decades ago.

Comment: They produce the same hash result for the same input. The real question is are you providing the same input to the hashing functions on the C# side and the SQL Server side? It's impossible to say because your question doesn't include the actual code that you're attempting to use, so please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71782224/edit) your question to rectify that.

Comment: your right, i checked and it does. my bad. thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

I have double checked and they do produce the same result. Sorry